# Navigation Drawer Not Working with AppCompat Theme

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme

Navigation Drawer Is Not With AppCompactActivity
My Code is

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="INBOX"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

tool_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/PrimaryColor"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" />
```

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_material"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        app:border_color="#FF000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Geevarughese"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profile_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="nestofrubin@live.com"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.geevarughese.nav;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Defining Variables
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.inbox:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inbox Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.starred:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stared Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.sent_mail:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Send Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.drafts:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Drafts Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.allmail:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All Mail Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.trash:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Trash Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.spam:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Spam Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();






    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ContentFragment.java

```
package com.example.geevarughese.nav;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 04-06-2015.
 */
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_fragment,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/inbox"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_3d_rotation_black_24dp"
            android:title="Inbox" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/starred"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_accessibility_black_24dp"
            android:title="Starred" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/sent_mail"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_balance_black_24dp"
            android:title="Sent Mail" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drafts"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
            android:title="Draft" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/allmail"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
            android:title="All Mail" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/trash"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_alarm_add_black_24dp"
            android:title="Trash" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/spam"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            android:title="Spam" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="PrimaryColor">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="PrimaryDarkColor">#1976D2</color>
</resources>
```

I tried everything that i know. but the app doesn't opens.

My logcat error is:

```
 08-19 02:11:09.109    8809-8809/com.example.geevarughese.nav E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.geevarughese.nav, PID: 8809
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geevarughese.nav/com.example.geevarughese.nav.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
            at com.example.geevarughese.nav.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geevarughese.nav" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml, it's saying you haven't applied the correct theme to the activity.

Comment: No, do you have sets of styles like v21, v7, styles.xml???

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml added to the above code

Comment: Im using Only styles.xml

Comment: use this theme in your manifest `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

Comment: Not working. Logcat shows Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Change the activity theme to one of the `NoActionBar` variants to solve your latest issue.

Comment: I tried it .but it throws previous exception again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your styles.xml file with this.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```